# Use a CSS rule to set all elements' background color except those that are partially transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set the background color of all elements in any webpage to a specific color. This can be done with a CSS rule like this one:

```
* {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

But I've noticed this hides or doesn't work properly with elements whose computed 'background-color' style is defined with a RGBA code (that is, elements that are partially transparent, if I'm not wrong). Here's an example from Google Images:

[image: Google Images: hidden images due to CSS rule]

I've been able to determine which these elements are with JavaScript thanks to the [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method but now I'm trying to solve this only with CSS. Is there any way I can use a CSS selector to exclude them from the rule? Taking in mind that the style properties that I believe can be relevant (background, background-color, opacity, etc.) won't be defined with inline CSS in most cases.

EDIT: this would be the result I want to get (obtained here using JavaScript):

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);`

Comment: probably because some elements have borders.add     `border: none !important;`
then it will be gone

Comment: @mkaatman Thanks for your answer. I've tried to change the opacity of all elements too but what I need is to exclude from the rule the elements that are not opaque.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha Thanks for your answer. I've tried your suggestion but I don't want to modify any other proprerty apart from the background color :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS styles are overlapped rather than  Overridden.

but All these rules are broken by using  '!important;'
which overlap on top of every style even if they are written after '!important' .

so edit your code as

```html
   * {
background-color: black;
}
```

then try applying separate background colors to
each  or  tag   which allows you to gain more control of the background colors  you want.

Comment: '!important' is definitely breaking the styles in some pages. It's the easiest way to make sure a property is applied but I guess I can't use it like this. I'll try to remove it and add more rules. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've done it but it doesn't show publicly until I get 15 reputation 